# iOS trigger single cell tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table containing 200-300 cells with different heights + one cell containing UITextView (such table is used to read and send messages). I need to dynamically adjust cell (containing UITextView) height while typing text. I use the next code in order to trigger `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

But this triggers calling `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for all rows. This slows down performance if table has many rows. Another approach could be to use `UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` method, but this cause keyboard to disappear (UITextView resigns first responder).

Is it possible to trigger calling `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` only for single row or there are any other approaches how to dynamically resize table cell?

Comment: Tried overwriting the textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: function and set the cell accordingly there? (just be sure you know which cell you are editing.) Also can you tell me your use of the textfield a little bit more? Maybe I can give you a better answer then.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus What would you offer to do inside `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`? I use UITextView to enter text :) and it is subview of UITableViewCell.contentView

Answer (score 3):

To reload only certain rows use:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]; 
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```